# Creating a png with specific rgb values (mac)

Tags: macos, png, rgb

I'm using a Mac. When I try creating a png with specific rgb values (i.e. 128,0,0), this is fine (I've tried using both GIMP and photoshop).
Now when I open the png file, the color looks slightly different. And when I use the DigitalColor Meter, the rgb values don't match anymore (the 128,0,0 file became 106,7,0).

What's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you steps in Gimp under WinXP and do not see any difference. 
When you save PNG file do you set some conversion options?

Update:
This link have same more info about color management on Mac OS X and may be a solution for you problem: [Color management](http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/).
My guess is that you have problem with default color management applied in Mac.